# Kendo UI Grd with kendo Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had a Kendo UI grid with inline editing. And one of my fields/column I use [kendo upload](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/index). And with the kendo upload I used `saveUrl` into `upload.php` file.

```js
{ field: "propertyLogo", title:"Logo", editor: fileUploadEditor },

function fileUploadEditor(container, options) {
  $('<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload"  /> ')
  .appendTo(container)
  .kendoUpload({ 
    multiple:false,
    async: {
      saveUrl: "upload.php", 
      autoUpload: true,
    },
    validation: {
      allowedExtensions: [".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg"]
    },
    success: onSuccess,
    upload: onUpload,
    progress: onProgress
  });
}
```

In my `upload.php` I try to `echo` the `$file` to check the result but it display nothing. I wonder am I do a right way? is there any sample/demo for kendo grid with kendo upload?

```js
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
  $file = $_FILES['fileUpload'];
  echo $file;
}else{
  echo "Access Denied!";
}
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($_FILES['fileUpload'])`.